# How to call a random function within another function without it being executed separately each time in Python?

Tags: python

The purpose of the code is to build a rock, paper, scissor game against the computer.

```
import random

def computer():
    comp = random.choice([0,1,2])
    if comp ==0:
        print "Computer throws rock",
    elif comp==1:
        print "Computer throws paper"
    elif comp==2:
        print "Computer throws scissors"
    return comp
print computer()

def throwing(a):
    if a == 0:
        print "Player throws rock"
    elif a == 1:
        print "Player throws paper"
    elif a  ==2:
        print "Player throws scissors"
    if (a-computer())%3 > (computer()-a)%3:
        print "Computer wins"
    elif a == computer():
        print "Draw"
    else:
        print "Player wins"

throwing(0)
```

I would expect it to return something like this:

```
Computer throws rock
0
Player throws paper
Player wins
```

but instead it returns

```
Computer throws rock
0
Player throws rock
Computer throws rock Computer throws scissors
Computer throws paper
Player wins
```

It seems that each time I call the function `computer()` within the function `throwing(a)` it doesn't take the aforegenerated random number but instead generates a new number each time, causing both the message to appear two extra times and totally messing up the correct rock-paper-scissor results.

How can I call the random-number-generating function `computer()` within the function `throwing()` for it just to keep its original value consistently?

Comment: btw you should upgrade to `python3`. python 2 has been deprecated since Januay 1, 2020!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.
That's not how computers work.

You have a problem in your logic: you tell the computer to run some code, when you don't actually want it to run that code.
And that is not going to succeed, no matter what programming language you are using.

If you want the computer to "throw" only once, then you must call `computer()` only once!

But, since you need the result later, you have to save that result:

```
import random

def computer():
    comp = random.choice([0,1,2])
    if comp == 0:
        print "Computer throws rock",
    elif comp == 1:
        print "Computer throws paper"
    elif comp == 2:
        print "Computer throws scissors"
    return comp
comp = computer()
print comp

def throwing(player, comp):
    if player == 0:
        print "Player throws rock"
    elif player == 1:
        print "Player throws paper"
    elif player == 2:
        print "Player throws scissors"
    if (player - comp) % 3 > (comp - player) % 3:
        print "Computer wins"
    elif player == comp:
        print "Draw"
    else:
        print "Player wins"

throwing(0, comp)
```

Answer (score 1):

You call the function multiple times. Read the output into a variable so you just call the function once.

Like this:

```
import random

def computer():
    comp = random.choice([0,1,2])
    if comp ==0:
        print "Computer throws rock",
    elif comp==1:
        print "Computer throws paper"
    elif comp==2:
        print "Computer throws scissors"
    return comp
print computer()

def throwing(a):
    if a == 0:
        print "Player throws rock"
    elif a == 1:
        print "Player throws paper"
    elif a  ==2:
        print "Player throws scissors"

    computer_result = computer()

    if (a-computer_result )%3 > (computer_result -a)%3:
        print "Computer wins"
    elif a == computer_result:
        print "Draw"
    else:
        print "Player wins"

# Test all possible choices
throwing(0)
throwing(1)
throwing(2)
```

I didn't run it, but this should work :-)

Comment: Yes it works thank you!! I further had to delete "print computer()" cause it served no purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In your original code, you are calling computer 3 times. Instead call it once and store its return value in a variable.
And please, always leave a blank space around operators, and use print as a function, even if it is usable as a keyword in Python 2, because in Python 3 it is not a keyword anymore, and your code will be full of SyntaxErrors if you ever want to switch your Python version !

```py
import random

def computer():
    comp = random.choice([0, 1, 2])
    if comp == 0:
        print("Computer throws rock")
    elif comp == 1:
        print("Computer throws paper")
    elif comp == 2:
        print("Computer throws scissors")
    return comp

def throwing(a):
    comp = computer()
    print(comp)
    if a == 0:
        print("Player throws rock")
    elif a == 1:
        print("Player throws paper")
    elif a == 2:
        print("Player throws scissors")
    
    if (a - comp) % 3 > (comp - a) % 3:
        print("Computer wins")
    elif a == comp:
        print("Draw")
    else:
        print("Player wins")

throwing(0)
```